# ReactJS and bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have a reactJS application and I would like to integrate bootstrap.  I have the following index.html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Whats my junk worth</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Just+Another+Hand' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body class="body_background">
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>

     <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>
```

I tried laying out some simple pages with code such as this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        Put out some test code
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        Put out some test code
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        Put out some test code
    </div>
</div>
```

The above sample generated 3 lines of output instead of spanning across a single row.  I also tried changing class= to className= but that had no effect.

Is there anything else that I need to include in order to make use of bootstrap classes?

Comment: Do you also have bootstrap installed using npm and imported in root component? Also share your full code in index.html

Comment: Also check this thread for more details https://www.techiediaries.com/react-bootstrap/

Comment: @Think-Twice I have provided my entire index.html

Comment: CAn you move bundle.js to the last after bootstrap cdn .js and before body close tag. I think bundle.js is loaded first and then bootstrap is getting loaded. Perhaps that’s the issue

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) package. You wouldn't waste you time on such things. Just components, just functionality.

It'll look something like this:

```
<Row className="show-grid">
    <Col xs={6} md={4}></Col>
    <Col xs={6} md={4}></Col>
    <Col xs={6} md={4}></Col>
</Row>
```

**UPD**

Bootstrap has [getting started](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/) guide which explains how should you handle your assets. Hope it'll help

Comment: I was wondering about that.  If I install react-bootstrap, I assume I remove the stylesheet and 3 scripts I link to in my Index.html file, right?

Comment: @JonathanSmall made an UPD

Comment: Yes. They are not required

Answer (score 1):

You can use [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) and convert your code into the following:

```
<Row className="show-grid">
    <Col xs={6} md={4}></Col>
    <Col xs={6} md={4}></Col>
    <Col xs={6} md={4}></Col>
</Row>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code and Bootstrap references should work the way you have it.

> "I tried laying out some simple pages with code"

How? Did you put the html into a Component render(), or did you put it directly in the template? Either way it should work. Remember too that the `sm` breakpoint is 576px so the columns will stack vertically if the viewport with is less than 576px.

Working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/5vm72q34qk

P.S. - react-bootstrap doesn't yet support Bootstrap 4.

Comment: I put the html in my render().  And I tested it with Chrome and I set the output device to iPad (768x1024) and the <div>'s get stacked as if bootstrap isn't even processing.